# Where are Unix errno constants in Rust?

Tags: linux, unix, rust

I am writing a program and there are a lot of places where
UNIX error codes are required. Is there any standard place or library with predefined set of these constants in Rust? Maybe there is a way to import them from standard C headers.

It's a minor issue and I could define these constants at my own source code but I'd like to know all the options.

I need to return them rather than to parse and convert to human readable strings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Many of these constants are available through the [libc](https://crates.io/crates/libc) crate. It also offers bindings to the functions which you'd presumably call before checking for the error codes, so you should be using it anyway if you aren't already.